# How to deploy a single HTML file to static hosting and have it show up for requests to my domain

Tags: website-design, phpmyadmin, static-content

Yes, the title is right. I would like to use a completely static HTML file as a website.

Well, I must confess I have absolutely zero knowledge in this area.

My provider is using phpMyAdmin and sFTP. I've already uploaded via the sFTP the HTML file I would like to use as a website. What to do next? I have absolutely no idea. I don't need a database. Basically, all I need is to open an HTML file when someone types in the address of my page and that's it.

I'm fully aware that my question may sound a bit silly but I couldn't find a how-to guide.

Comment: What is the name of your HTML file?  Is it `index.html`?

Comment: It's page.html but I certainly can rename it.

Comment: Probably,  all you need to do is rename it. If it doesnt work then add the error message to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most situations renaming your only HTML file `index.html` is all that you need to do.  That is because web servers are nearly universally configured to serve `index.html` for any requests that resolve to the directory containing it.

Alternatively you could reconfigure your web server to serve `page.html` instead of or in addition to `index.html`.  On most static hosting plans that would be accomplished by creating a `.htaccess` file containing:

```
DirectoryIndex page.html index.html
```

See [the documentation for Apache's `DirectoryIndex` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)

Comment: Thank you! I will try.

Bitvise SFTP shows two directories: public_html and tmp. And several files: .bash_logout, .bashrc and .profile. Should I copy my index.php to public_html folder?

Comment: Yes, the `public_html` directory would be the one that is configured to be the document root for your site.

Comment: Hostgator has documentation for how to do this:  https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/public-html-folder  It sounds like your hosting company has a very similar setup and Hostgator's docs should work in your case.

Comment: You're absolutely right! It does indeed work! My HTML opened. Just one small problem. There's no additional content like pictures. I saved them in a separate folder in the public_html folder.

Comment: If you saved the images in a separate folder in public_html you need to ensure the html code includes the relative path before the image - eg <img src="/subdirectory/filename.jpg">    Subdirectory here would be the part after but excluding public_html  - Either that or move the images into the same directory as the html file.